# FetchEvent error results in a network error response: the promise was rejected

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

When I load my test site (Laravel/Vue) I'm getting the alert:

> The FetchEvent for "http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php" resulted in a
> network error response: the promise was rejected.

Other posters here with a similar problem usually had a service worker involved, so I turned off that part of the code and cleared the caches - but the problem remained.

My first problem is that I just don't know where to look to try and find the source of the problem. How do I find the FetchEvent for ...index.php?

Thanks/Tom